# File Screening Templates - Large Images

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I've got a Windows Server 2008 R2 which works as a File Server and will replace the current production file servers.
In the past my company experienced a lot of troubles with data, due the users not caring about what they were dumping in the old file servers. So I'm testing File Screens and so far it's working OK with .pst and .ost files.

Now, I want a new File Screen Template which is triggered only when any image, larger than 1MB, is uploaded. There's no option for file size screening!
I can only chose the extension for the templates but no size.

Hope you can help!
Thanks :)

Simone

Comment: Might be easier to simply do a nightly cleanup and write a script to troll the users shares and cleanup any messes they made.  But you might want to consider enabling previous versions so they can recover them within a certain time period.  Then add a bit to the script to tell them you removed their file and how to find and recover it.

Comment: Yeah I wanted to avoid any custom script, and in any case, for now, I'm only setting it up in Passive Mode, since I do not want to remove anything production critical..